# iOS - Reload UITableView to Fix Cell Label Height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

Well, this sounds totally weird and I have been spending the last 3 hours trying to fix it. I have a table view with custom cell that contains two labels. The labels heights are variables and calculated using the method `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode`.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:sPrefixStringWithColon, [self getPrefixStringAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                                                  cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                                                  kTableViewCellLabelWidth,
                                                                  [self getSizeForPrefixStringAtIndexPath:indexPath].height);

cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellDetailsLabel.text = [self getDetailStringAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellDetailsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellDetailsLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                                                   cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.frame.origin.y + cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel.frame.size.height + 3,
                                                                   kTableViewCellLabelWidth,
                                                                   [self getSizeForDetailsStringAtIndexPath:indexPath].height);

[cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellPrefixLabel sizeToFit];
[cell.tariffPlanCellContentView.cellDetailsLabel sizeToFit];
```

At the first load of the table view, all cells appear with one line only. Only when I scroll the table view (or programmatically reloading the table view "again"), the labels are fixed! I don't know why it's doing that? `cellPrefixLabel` and `cellDetailsLabel` are inside a custom cell loaded from nib. Both have `numberOfLines = 0`

**Update**

1. I am not using Auto-Layout, I am still supporting iOS 5.
2. The application is working fine on iOS 6 and the bug is only on iOS 7 beta 6! Is it due to the beta version? Does any one face anything like this?
3. I removed sizeToFit and the same problem exists. In fact, sizeToFit doesn't help at all and it's not required on iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Move all you UITableviewcell additions code to the delegate method and give it a try

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Well, this could lightening, however after finding that it works fine on iOS 6, I am suspecting a bug in iOS 7 beta 6

Answer (score 0):

Are you using auto-layout?  If so then you probably shouldn't be calling sizeToFit.  The size of the label would be inferred from its intrinsicContentSize, which is updated after the text is set.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118021/how-to-resize-superview-to-fit-all-subviews-with-autolayout/18155803#18155803) for additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to know why. It is in fact a bug (or this is how it looks). The method sizeWithFont... is used with one of iOS 7 new font text styles. It seems that this method doesn't count for this new font correctly. Hopefully, tomorrow's GM would fix this bug. If not, I have to use a workaround by adding about 10 points to the height.

What does this has to do with a reload fixing the height (if using sizeToFit), I really don't know. The whole new dynamic font system seems fragile.