# How to make UITableView row height respond to user's preferred text size (Dynamic Type)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, textkit

I would like the `UITableView`'s row height to respond to changes in the user's preferred text size. For example, when the preferred text size increases, I would like to increase the row height by a proportional amount. Here's what I have so far:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // observe when user changes preferred text size
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(preferredContentSizeChanged:) name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)preferredContentSizeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{ 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // leverage Text Kit's Dynamic Type
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"All work and no play...";

    return cell;
}
```

So what's the best way to calculate a row height that reflects the user's preferred text size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize superview to fit all subviews with autolayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118021/how-to-resize-superview-to-fit-all-subviews-with-autolayout)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently accomplished this and found it to be very simple. Instead of using `sizeWithFont:` you should use the new `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` method in iOS 7.

Set up your table view cell as usual and specify the `preferredFontForTextStyle:` on your text label as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //set your table view cell content here
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolour sit amet."];
    [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
    [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];

    return cell;
}
```

Then to correctly determine the size of the text label, evaluate the `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` to calculate the required height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //add your table view cell content here
    NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]};

    CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];

    return ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(frame);
}
```

You may want to subclass your table view cell also to listen for `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` notifications at which point you can update your UI when the user changes their preferences in Settings.app

```
- (void)contentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotificationHandler:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[self textLabel] setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
}
```

Should you require additional padding around the text label, you can define a constant value such as

```
static CGFloat const TableViewCellPadding = 10.0;
```

With this in place, you can either add a constant value to the value returned from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
return (ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(frame) + TableViewCellPadding);
```

Or you could inset the frame returned from `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` as such:

```
CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];

frame = CGRectInset(frame, 0.0, TableViewCellPadding);
```

Comment: So you're setting the row height to the exact height of the text without adding any padding above and below the text? The rows are going to be very short and visually unappealing. I think you have provided only half a solution here. How would you calculate the padding?

Comment: Padding would be added at the users behest. I actually do this myself by defining a static constant which is applied using `CGRectInset` or more preferably added to the height returned from `CGRectGetHeight`.

Comment: In your code, row height is returned by a table view delegate method, so when exactly are you going to add a constant value to the row height? And how would you use CGRectInset to configure the height of a table cell? Post the code.

Comment: I omitted the code for adding padding as this wasn't part of the OPs question. Using `CGRectInset` or adding a constant value to the value returned from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is a simple process. Regardless, I have amended my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -3):

use this method:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      NSString *fieldLabel = labelCell.textLabel.text;

     CGSize textSize = [fieldLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:17.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
     float newHeight = textSize.height+22.0f;
     return newHeight;
 }
```

Add below code to cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

      UILabel *lblfield=[[UILabel alloc] init];
      NSString *fieldLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",labelCell.textLabel.text];
      CGSize textSize = [fieldLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:17.0f]      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
      float newHeight = textSize.height+22.0f;
      lblfield.frame=CGRectMake(10, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, newHeight);
      lblfield.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
      lblfield.text=strusername;
      [cell addSubview:lblfield];
      return cell;
 }
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but unless I missed it, this code doesn't actually use Text Kit's Dynamic Type.

Comment: means? what do you want to say? Is there any thing missing?

Comment: Don't you need to call UIFont's preferredFontForTextStyle: at some point to get the user's preferred text size?

Comment: you can putyour own UIFont style inplaceof Georgia and fontsize

Comment: This implementation doesn't make use of the newer iOS 7 methods for both `preferredFontForTextStyle` and `boundingRectWithSize`. `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated in iOS7.