# iOS - UITableViewCell does not keep system font size

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, uifont

I am using the first answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115053/how-to-make-uitableview-row-height-respond-to-users-preferred-text-size-dynami) question, and it is working, but when I reload my tableview, it is losing the text size. I have subclassed as the answer suggests. How do I get the UITableView to keep the system Dynamic Type size when the UITableView reloads?

The delegates are set, and again, when I have the UITableView in focus, switch to the Settings, adjust font size, and switch back to the UITableView, it reflects the change. When I reload the UITableView, the font is back to the standard size. I am using a standard detail cell.

Here is the code I use to set the look of the cell:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = building.name;
    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = building.address;
    [cell.detailTextLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]];
```

Comment: In what method is that code?