# Custom View with dynamic Height as UITableView Header ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my project,i have a 1.MovieplayerView,2.a label with dynamic content,3.a tableView with variable number of rows.

I was doing this with all these views in scrollView.But i always have the issue with dynamic height of the label.it sometime overlaps the tableView.

I came to know that  we can use customView as the tableView header.How this can be done with variable content Height and autolayout?I am new to iOS.Any suggestion ??

I know how to add a view as the header to a table.But when the contents in the view changes,it overlaps the contents of the tableView.

I went through
[How to resize superview to fit all subviews with autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118021/how-to-resize-superview-to-fit-all-subviews-with-autolayout/18155803#18155803),[How do I set the height of tableHeaderView (UITableView) with autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982558/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-tableheaderview-uitableview-with-autolayout)

Can some one give a simple example on how to do this?Or tell me if it is better to use a scrollview and add all these views as its subviews? any suggestion would be realy helpful.Thanks.

Comment: can  u check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following code is this what u want to achieve can u clearify me please

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 200, 40)];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ %@",selectedCategory];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    label.textColor = ThemeColor;
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.933f green:0.933f blue:0.933f alpha:1.00f]];
    return view;
}
```

Don't forget to place this in nib of `UITableView`

[image]

Comment: Tanq for your effort nischal..but this question was asked 3 months ago.I added all those things(1.MovieplayerView,2.a label with dynamic content,3.a tableView with variable number of rows.)as the subview of uitableview header.It is working well.+1 for the answer.:)

Comment: you are welcome dude i saw it on stack overflow active list so that i answered it.

Comment: if u find the answer appropriate the u can accept it too . i have gave u +1 too

Comment: This code alone won't work well.I had to reload the table,get the tableview height,label height etc and reset the tableVIew header frame.Also the autolayout constraints should work well.Here i have one tableview inside another tableview header.But it is better to use this method rather than using a scrollview to do this.Scrollview+autolayout is complicated.

Comment: if u gt trouble with autolayout then feel free to post the question ad inform me . i m interested to solve autolayout issues

Comment: Thanks man..:) u have any mail id?if i have any issues i can raise a question and send you the link.

Comment: hadanischal@gmail.com u can mail me and update me ab ur latest question in stackoverflow dude

Comment: do u have any idea ab this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842086/forward-geocoding-doesnt-give-correct-results

Comment: i dont have much idea about geocoding.:)

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidAppear,
1. Get the height of the dynamic content, then set the height of your tableHeaderView accordingly.
2. Set the headerView again so the table view can refresh:
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to interpret your question regarding your use of the scroll view.  If what you want is a custom view as the table view header, you could override this method in your table view class:

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
```