# Forward geocoding doesnt give correct results

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geocoding

I didn't get correct results for Forward geocoding in certain cases. When I search for some places or hotel it shows result of some others places or areas. I have got following code. I study the following [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/forward-geocoding-for-location-in-previous-ios5-devices/). What url should i place to get correct results.

how can we implement the following given in following site

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete

> A request for addresses containing "Vict" with results in French:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=API_KEY
>   A request for cities containing "Vict" with results in Brazilian
>   Portuguese:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(cities)&language=pt_BR&key=API_KEY

I have implemented following but it doesn't give the results as i aspected

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)addressLocation{
     NSError *error = nil;

      //   NSString *lookUpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", SearchtextField];
       //  NSString *API_KEY=@"AIzaSyB27SkGBzvEYKcxvZ5nmOVWvrA-6Xqf-7A";
        NSString *API_KEY=@"AIzaSyCHcqJcqZbP1XpU-WB4VfRct5hpdgqisSY";
        NSString *lookUpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&region=np&key=%@", SearchtextField,API_KEY];



        lookUpString = [lookUpString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

        NSData *jsonResponse = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookUpString]];

        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *locationArray = [[[jsonDict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"];


        NSString *statusString = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"status"];

          if ([statusString isEqualToString:@"OK"])
        {
                locationArray = [locationArray objectAtIndex:0];

                Str_Latitude= [locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
                Str_Longitude= [locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];

                NSLog(@"LatitudeString:%@ & LongitudeString:%@", Str_Latitude, Str_Longitude);
                /*Google place latitude Longitude*/
                Arr_LatLong = @[Str_Latitude,Str_Longitude];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:Str_Latitude forKey:@"Str_Latitude"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:Str_Longitude forKey:@"Str_Longitude"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                GogLatitude = [Str_Latitude doubleValue];
                Goglongitude = [Str_Longitude doubleValue];

                if (Bool_SearchField) {
                    [self getGoogleAddress];
                    Bool_SearchField=FALSE;
                }else{

                }


        }else{

                UIAlertView *alertview =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Address not found" message:@"make sure you enter a valid address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                  [alertview show];

                   NSLog(@"Something went wrong, couldn't find address");
                  [self.tableView reloadData];
            }

        GogLocation.latitude = GogLatitude;
        GogLocation.longitude = Goglongitude;

        return GogLocation;
    }
```

> When i search for radission in `maps.google.com` it shows as below

[image]

> But when i search in my app it shows different locations then what I search
>    [image]

Comment: Seems like there are some auto-correction in the Google Maps. Does this piece of code show you the correct result when your have the correct spelling?

Comment: it just give the location but not the what i get. what is the url to use auto correct can u please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You can either take use of the [Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes), which [according to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:NP), should be `NP`. So add `&region=np` at the end of your query.

Or you can use the [Viewport Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports) to set the bounds of your searches.

Answer (score 1):

I have done what you have asked in one of my apps, but the url is different.

I am posting the function that gets called each time i input something in a text field.

```
-(void) startAutocomplete{
    NSString* baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&key=AIzaSyDz3HAmNY8NsgIhtA8gtbH-QA08Lg9tej4&types=all", self.locationTextfield.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"Url: %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        if (connectionError!=nil) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:connectionError.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show ] ;
        }else{
            NSError *error = nil;
            self.searchResult= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

            //NSLog(@"result:%@",self.searchResult);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: it is far better then what i have been implementing can u give me some idea where i could place  <  &components=country:np  > so only the results from Nepal is displayed

Comment: I think you can just append &components=country:np at the end of the above url.

Comment: Please search more on google places search api and find out how to specify country for filtering results.