# In IOS Google places API with web service gave output in Unicode Character 'DEVANAGARI LETTER NA' (U+0928)

Tags: ios, unicode, geocoding, unicode-string, google-places

In Google Places API Web Service I get output in  Unicode Character 'DEVANAGARI LETTER NA' (U+0928) how can I handle that

I have found two URL for **Google places API**

```
 NSString* baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&key=%@&types=all", SearchtextField,API_KEY];

 NSString* baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&location=27.7089603,85.3261328&radius=50000&key=%@&types=all",SearchtextField,API_KEY];
```

language value    `&language=en-GB` doesn't work out  to get only english results

```
NSString* baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&language=en-GB&location=27.7089603,85.3261328&radius=50000&key=%@&types=all",SearchtextField,API_KEY];
```

**I get results like below**

```
searchResult :(
    "Lainchaur, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal",
    "Lainchaur Marg, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal",
    "Lainchaur Bus Stop, Leknath Marg, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal",
    "Lainchaur Banquet, \U0932\U0948\U0928\U091a\U094c\U0930, \U092e\U0927\U094d\U092f\U092e\U093e\U091e\U094d\U091a\U0932, \U0928\U0947\U092a\U093e\U0932"
)
```

when i print the string for Unicode character it is like this

```
Lainchaur Banquet, लैनचौर, मध्यमाञ्चल, नेपाल
```

I need to implement geocode from search text  to get respective Latitude, Longitude. I have used following URL for it . every things works fine but when there is Unicode Character geocode cant be performed

```
 NSString *lookUpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", SearchtextField];
```

**I have previous questions related to that too**

[Forward geocoding doesnt give correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842086/forward-geocoding-doesnt-give-correct-results)