# How do I make one container view uses its "intrinsicContentSize" while the other container view takes rest of the space with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

The container view is created using [[UIView alloc] init]; I then put other UIViews, like UIButton, UILabel, UIImageView inside it using autolayout.

My goal is to let one container use its "intrinsicContentSize" while the other takes rest of the space. But it turns out that I have 3 problems,

1. Although each subview has its intrinsicContentSize, the container view doesn't have it, its intrinsicContentSize always returns -1
2. Without intrinsicContentSize, content hugging and compression resistance priorities are meaningless.
3. I tried systemLayoutSizeFittingSize on container, but it always return 0. I didn't figure out why?

How do I achieve my goal then

Update: I figured out why systemLayoutSizeFittingSize always return 0 as explained here [get container size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30511982/301513) but have not achieved my goal yet

Comment: `UIView` doesn't have an intrinsic content size.  You'll need to set the size some other way and use content hugging to get other views to fill the available space.

Comment: But I also see someone mentioned "a plain UIView used as a container has no intrinsic size. So, its content hugging and compression resistance priorities are meaningless." What then.

Comment: Create a subclass of UIView for your container, and implement `intrinsicContentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

**Subclass UIView**

subclass UIView and add all the subview inside...then override `intrinsecContentSize` and return the size of the container.

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(0, self.subview1.intrinsicContentSize().width + self.subview2.intrinsicContentSize().width)
}
```

now `intrinsecContentSize` will give you the right value. Don't forget to invalidate the `intrinsecContentSize` before update the content inside the container with `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`.

**Use UIStackView or OAStackView**

If your app support only iOS9+ you can use UIStackView, otherwise you can use [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView).

Comment: I have to say that is the last thing I want to do :(

Comment: I agree with you is not the easiest solution. I have edited the question.