# Mixing self sizing cells with calculated sizes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

My initial task is to have equal widths of cells and make them fill the entire row of the collection view with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Is there a way to calculate height of cells using autolayout, but provide width from `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

In `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, calculate the height using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` with a CGSize of your desired width, and a height large enough to fit your largest content.

e.g. for cell width of 100 (large maximum height of 999):

`[collectionViewCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:CGSizeMake(100, 999)];`

Beware though, if you have multiline `UILabel`'s, as you will need to fiddle with `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. More details, albeit for a table view, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18155803/4082770).